# cmd not showing some files

Tags: windows, cmd

Here is something odd. When I run:
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.run("C:\Windows\System32\PnPutil.exe")
I get a 80070002 cannot find specified file. I know that file is there. So I ran:
    oShell.run("cmd /K C:\Windows\System32\PnPutil.exe")
I get a command shell and browse to C:\Windows\System32. PnPutil.exe is not there. I can browse to the folder in explorer, it is there. What gives? Am I in an alternate cmd universe?

Comment: Does `cmd /K C:\Windows\System32\PnPutil.exe` work from the command line?

Comment: eryksun, you are absolutely correct! I new it was in a different environment, just didn't understand why it wouldn't just show the file. So in reality, it was never in the system32 folder, just appears to be.  No, how do I mark yours as the correct answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you're running 32-bit cmd.exe on 64-bit Windows. `%SystemRoot%\System32` gets redirected to `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64` for 32-bit apps, which is where the 32-bit DLLs and EXEs reside (MSDN: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187)). But there's no 32-bit version of PnPutil.exe. Try `C:\Windows\Sysnative\PnPutil.exe`. The `Sysnative` virtual directory lets 32-bit apps access the real `System32` directory.