# How can I run the 64-bit version of a Windows utility (such as msiexec) in a 32-bit batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer, win64

I have a batch file that (for compatibility reasons) runs in a 32-bit `cmd.exe` process.  However, I now need to launch the 64-bit version of a Windows command-line tool, in this case `msiexec`.  How can I do this?

*Additional detail:*

I am using a batch file to install various software products.  For maximum compatibility with older products, the batch file is running as a 32-bit process.  However, I now need to install Intel Haxm, which requires the 64-bit version of `msiexec`.

I tried already to call `c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe`, but when doing this the Windows installer log file still says:

> `=== Verbose logging started: 14.04.2015  14:27:53  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: c:\windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe ===`

Comment: In Vista+ it's available as `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msiexec.exe`.

Comment: @eryksun - rather `%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe`

Comment: @npocmaka, rather not. Read about the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187) for WOW64 processes.

Comment: @eryksun post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.  I did not know this.

Comment: Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27520259/205580) I wrote a few months ago.

Comment: @Frank: I've rewritten your question to generalize it, so it can serve as a canonical question and answer.  This will make it more useful to future readers and also allow us to close similar questions as a duplicate of this one.  (I was rather surprised to discover there wasn't a canonical version of this question already!)  Note that if you are unhappy with any of my changes, you can revert my edit and/or edit it further yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the `sysnative` alias, as described in the MSDN article [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx):

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.
>
> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:**  The Sysnative alias was added starting with Windows Vista.

So, in a batch file, you would say something like

```
%windir%\sysnative\msiexec /install product.msi /passive /norestart
```

Or if you need to run another batch file

```
%windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c silent_install.bat
```

Note that `sysnative` is not supported in the 64-bit versions of Windows XP or Windows 2003 unless hotfix 942589 has been installed.  [See this answer for one workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800065/886887)